# error al verificar si hay un usuario repetido

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

hola que tal estoy haciendo un registro con php y msql
este es mi codigo php

```
<?php
 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
 $db = mysqli_select_db($link,"datos_usuario") or die ("<h2>Error de Conexion</h2>");

 if (isset($_POST['nombre'])){
     $nombre =$_POST['nombre'];
     $apellido =$_POST['apellido'];
     $clave =$_POST['clave'];
     $rclave =$_POST['rclave'];
     $telefono =$_POST['telefono'];
     $edad =$_POST['edad'];
     $email =$_POST['email'];

 }

 if ($clave != $rclave) {
        die('Las contraseñas no coinciden, Verifique <br /> <a href="index.html">Volver</a>');
    }

 $nuevo_email=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM datos WHERE email='$email'"); 
 $verificar=mysqli_num_rows($nuevo_email);
 if($verificar>0);
 { 
 echo " 
 <p class='avisos'>La direccion de e-mail ya esta registrada</p> 
 <p class='avisos'><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)' class='clase1'>Volver atrás</a></p> 
 "; 
 } 
 mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO datos VALUES ('','$nombre','$apellido','$clave','$telefono','$edad','$email')")

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    .contenedor
    {
        width:1340px;
        height:1000px;
        line-height:400px;      
        text-align:center;
    }
    .contenedor>span {
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        line-height:normal;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="inicio_de_sesion.php">

    <div class='contenedor'>
        <span>felicidades ya estas registrado<br></span>
        <td><label><input type="submit" value="inicia sesion"></input></label></td>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

el registro ya funciona correctamente lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que me diga si hay un algun correo repetido si alguien lo coloca
esta es la parte del codigo que se supone que me dice si el correo ya esta en la base de datos

```
 $nuevo_email=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM datos WHERE email='$email'"); 
 $verificar=mysqli_num_rows($nuevo_email);
 if($verificar>0);
 { 
 echo " 
 <p class='avisos'>La direccion de e-mail ya esta registrada</p> 
 <p class='avisos'><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)' class='clase1'>Volver atrás</a></p> 
 "; 
 }
```

el código cumple su función pero deja registrar la idea es que me diga si hay algún correo ya registrado y no lo deje registrar

cabe aclarar que datos_usuario es la base de datos y datos es la tabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que poner la inserción en un `else`. Como lo tienes ahora, el código sigue su rumbo y llega siempre a la inserción.

Prueba así:

```
    if($verificar>0) 
    { 
         echo " 
         <p class='avisos'>La direccion de e-mail ya esta registrada</p> 
         <p class='avisos'><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)' class='clase1'>Volver atrás</a></p> 
         "; 
     } else {
         mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO datos VALUES ('','$nombre','$apellido','$clave','$telefono','$edad','$email')");
    }
```

Aparte de eso, convendría que pongas una restricción en la base de datos, para impedir que haya duplicados en la columna `email`.

### Duda adicional

Dado que tienes dudas sobre la organización del código, es muy simple. Si tienes una condición como esta:

```
    if($verificar>0) 
    {
       #Aquí quiere decir que el email existe
       #Debes poner aquí todo lo que tiene que aparecer en ese caso
       #Por ejemplo: echo "El email existe"; 
    } else {
       #Aquí quiere decir que el email no existe
       #Debes poner aquí todo lo que tiene que aparecer en ese caso
       #Por ejemplo: echo "El email NO existe"; 
    }
       #Si aquí hay más código, el que sea, se ejecutará
       #Porque ya aquí no hay ninguna condición para que el código no se ejecute
       #Si aquí tienes algo que no debe mostrarse si el email no existe
       #Debes moverlo, poniéndolo en el else, como hiciste con el INSERT
```

### Más observaciones

- Parece que estás aprendiendo de un tutorial antiguo. En `mysqli` ya no es necesario conectar y seleccionar la base de datos posteriormente. Lo puedes hacer pasando un cuarto parámetro en la conexión. De modo que no será necesario usar `mysqli_select_db` si haces esto para conectar:

  ```
   $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","datos_usuario");
  ```
- Trata de usar el estilo orientado a objetos. Es mucho más claro y menos *verboso* que el estilo procedural.
- Usa consultas preparadas.
- Controla el flujo del código
- Para un futuro no lejano, trata de evitar la mezcla de código PHP y Javascript. Es mejor mandar los datos vía Ajax. Así mantienes a su respectivo nivel el código servidor y el código cliente y además, no será necesario recargar la página para mandar los datos al servidor.

Comment: ohhh gracias por los consejos, amigo pero al ejecutar el codigo con el else me suelta error (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE), expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\traductly\datos.php on line 27)

Comment: @DANIGIRALDO es cierto, cometí un error de sintaxis en la respuesta. Lo he corregido, prueba como está ahora.

Comment: okey amigo ahora si me funciono pero yo tengo un html el cual dice esto <body>
 <form action="inicio_de_sesion.php">

 <div class='contenedor'>
  <span>felicidades ya estas registrado<br></span>
  <td><label><input type="submit" value="inicia sesion"></input></label></td>
 </div>
 
</body>
</html> el codigo detecta que el email esta repetido y no lo registra pero igual aparece el codigo de ya estas regitrado fue error mio al no publicarlo en mi codigo de origen

Comment: @DANIGIRALDO no entiendo lo que me quieres decir en tu último comentario. Es lógico que si ya está registrado lo diga, ¿no?

Comment: me refiero a que identifica que el correo ya esta registrado y no lo registra y me muestra el mensaje "La direccion de e-mail ya esta registrada" pero ademas me muestra el mensaje en html, se supone que si el correo ya esta registrado solo me muestre el mensaje de que el email ya esta registrado

Comment: @DANIGIRALDO es por lo mismo que te dije antes. Tienes que organizar el código de modo que dentro del `else` pongas lo que necesites mostrar cuando el usuario no está registrado. Tienes que usar el  `if {  (condicion)   }  else  { ...  }`   para organizar cada cosa. No sé si me explico. Todo lo que pongas debajo se mostrará, como pasaba con la inserción, porque no la tenías dentro del bloque `if ... else  ...`

Comment: entonces que debo de cuadrar? quietar el html y colocar un echo ?

Comment: @DANIGIRALDO agregué un apartado **Duda adicional** a la pregunta, donde trato de explicártelo mejor. Es algo básico sobre los condicionales. Todo lo que haya fuera del `if` se mostrará en todos los casos, como ya dije, debes organizar el código según lo que necesites mostrar o no. Y eso lo puedes hacer con `echo` o poniendo contenido HTML o lo que quieras, pero dentro de los bloques donde deba aparecer ese contenido, no fuera de ellos.

Comment: Como dice @A.Cedano evitate todo esto y agrega un `UNIQUE INDEX` a la base de datos.

Comment: ohhh okey ya entendí pero como le puedo agregar un boton dentro de un echo?

Comment: @DANIGIRALDO con `echo "<button id=\"unBoton\">Soy un botón</button>";`

Comment: dentro echo puedo colocar cualquier código relacionado con html ?

Comment: Claro, puedes colocar cualquier código HTML. Y si es muy largo, puedes cerrar un bloque PHP poner el HTML como texto y luego abrir de nuevo el bloque PHP.